# How to prevent pdb files from being generated in unit test results "out" folder?

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

When I run unit tests via mstest.exe, the test results folder contains .pdb files. These files are not supposed to be there as they interfere with the automated build system. Is there any way to prevent those files from being generated?

Comment: Instead of preventing the generation of pdb files I'd rather try to get my build system to accept them. pdb files enable the display of more detailed error information such as line numbers which will be especially useful when testing.

Answer (score 2):

Running unit tests doesn't produce .pdb files.  Compiling the tests does.  Check your build settings.  It is the /pdb argument to the compiler, in case you are not using msbuild.

One exception, you could get .pdbs if you are unit-testing code that uses System.CodeDom.  In which case checking that you get the .pdbs ought to be part of the test.